# EF Core Linq for distinct rows

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I need help on linq method based query. I have tables below.

**ItemTable**

```
ItemId | Itemname
  1    | Item1
```

**StatusTable**

```
StatusId | Status
   S1    | NotOk
   S2    | Ok
   S3    | Unknown
```

I have a mapping table as below: It will have mappings like below with duplicated records. For simplicity, I did not include all the columns.

**ItemStatus**

```
ItemId | StatusId
   1   | S1
   1   | S1
   1   | S2
```

Need help with linq method based for displaying the data as below

```
ItemName | Status
  Item1  | NotOK, OK
```

But when I try with linq (method based not query based), I am getting duplicates like below. I do not want duplicate records to be included.

```
ItemName | Status
   Item1 | NotOK, NotOk, OK
```

I could not post the linq as it was too complex. I simplified the scenario and posted here. Please suggest right linq method based approach  for this scenario

I have given high level linq query (not so accurate, i just added for reference)

```
var dataQueryable = context.ItemTable
                .Join(context.ItemStatus.Select(a => a.ItemId).Distinct(), item=>item.ItemId, id=>id,(item,id) =>
                    new ReturnObject
                    {
                        ItemId = item.ItemId,
                        ItemName = item.ItemName,
                        Status = item.ItemStatus
                            .Where(e => e.ItemId == item.ItemId)
                            .Select(result => new ResultReturnObject()
                            {
                                Status = result.status
                            })
                            .ToList()
                    })
                .AsQueryable();
```

Comment: You show `ItemName` with value `1` in the results, but that is `ItemId` in the `ItemTable` - what should it be?

Comment: Please add  what code you tried in a way that we can reproduce the same issue.

Comment: I updated the ItemName. sorry for the typo.

Comment: `ItemStatus.Join(StatusTable,i_s => i_s.StatusId, s => s.StatusId, (i_s, s) => new { i_s.ItemId, s.Status }).GroupBy(i_s => i_s.ItemId).Select(isg => new { ItemId = isg.Key, Status = String.Join(", ", isg.Select(i_s => i_s.Status).Distinct())`

Comment: What EF are you using: LINQ to EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / EF Core 2.1 / EF Core 3.x?

Comment: I added the high level linq which I m trying

Comment: if there is a way to avoid duplicates, that would help. Making comma separated would be handled at the frontend/ui.

Comment: I've got an idea but my brain hurts at this moment. I'll come back to you tomorrow.

Comment: So here's my thought but I am not sure if it can be applied on your problem with LINQ. Item Status should be a flags enum (because an `Item` can have any of the states here, combined also). If you have it as a flag, you can a) combine all the flags of an `Item` with `|` without generating duplicates and you can b) print the result in the required way with `.ToString()`!

Answer (score 1):

I did something like that some months ago, I tried to recreated, is not the best solution but it could help to fin a better solution.
First of all is apply a group by **ItemName** and **Status** to eliminate duplicated

```
var result =
            from p in items
            select new
            {
                noDuplicated = (from pc in itemStatuses
                           join c in status on pc.StatusId equals c.StatusId
                           where pc.ItemId == p.ItemId
                           group p by new { p.ItemName,  c.Estatus }
                           into mygroup
                           select new { 
                               ItemName = mygroup.Key.ItemName, 
                               StatusName = mygroup.Key.Estatus 
                           })
            };
```

After that you gonna get this result:

```
ItemName | Status
Item1 | NotOK 
Item1 | OK
```

Finally you can apply another group only by **ItemName**

```
var grouped = result.Select(a => a.noDuplicated).SingleOrDefault()
                .GroupBy(e => new { e.ItemName }).ToList()
                .Select(eg => new
                {
                    ItmName = eg.Key.ItemName,
                    StatList = string.Join(",", eg.Select(i => i.StatusName))
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

In LINQ, whenever you want "Items with their sub-items", like "Schools with their Students", "Authors with their Books", "Customers with their Orders", or in your case: "Items with their Statusses", consider to use on of the [overloads of GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupjoin?view=netcore-3.1).

In a one-to-many relation this is fairly straightforward. You have a many-to-many relation between `Items` and `Statusses`. Therefore you need to GroupJoin with the junction table `ItemStatus` before you can get the `Statusses` that belong to this `Item`

```
var itemsWithTheirStatusses = dbContext.ItemsTable.GroupJoin(
    dbContext.ItemsStatusses,            // GroupJoin ItemsTable with junction table
    item => item.Id,                     // from every Item take the Id
    itemStatus => itemStatus.ItemId,     // from every itemStatus take the itemId

    // Parameter resultSelector: from every Item with its zero or more ItemStatusses
    // make one new object
    (item, itemStatussesOfThisItem) => new ...
```

What I did here, is I took all Items in the ItemsTable. From every Item in this table I took the Id. I searched every row in the ItemsStatusses table that refer to this Id.

So now I have an Item and all ItemStatusses that refer to this Item, and I need to make one new object. Each ItemStatus has a `StatusId`, so you can simply fetch the Status that belongs to this Id.

However, your problem is that you have several `itemStatussesOfThisItem` that refer to the same `Status`, in other words: that have the same value of `StatusId`.

You could first get the Statusses that belong to this Item and then remove duplicates. It is more efficient if you first remove the duplicate StatusId and then fetch the Status that has this Id.

Continuing the GroupJoin:

```
(item, itemStatussesOfThisItem) => new
{
    // Select only the Item properties that you plan to use:
    Id = item.Id,

    // if desired, add other item properties:
    Name = item.Name,
    ...

    // process the itemStatussesOfThisItem. You only want the Status
    // from every itemStatus of this item,  select only the StatusId
    // Remove the duplicate StatusIds
    // Get the Status with this StatusId
    // and select the Status properties that you want:
    Statusses = itemStatussesOfThisItem
        .Select(itemStatus => itemStatus.StatusId)   // get all StatusIds
        .Distinct()                                  // remove duplicate StatusIds
        .Select(statusId => dbContext.Statusses      // get the Status with this Id
             .Where(status => status.Id == statusId)
             
             // you are only interested in property Status:
             .Select(status => status.Status)
             .ToList(),
});
```

Example:

```
 Statusses          ItemsTable         ItemsStatusses
Id   Status         Id  Name            ItemId  StatusId
20   Ok             10   A                10       20 
21   NotOk          11   B                11       22
22   Unknown        12   C                11       22
                    13   D                10       21
                                          10       20
                                          11       20
                                          13       21
                                          13       21
```

At the beginning of parameter resultSelector you have `(item, itemStatussesOfThisItem)`:

- Item [10] with its ItemStatusses [10, 20] [10, 21] [10, 20]
- Item [11] with its ItemStatusses [11, 22] [11, 22] [11, 20]
- Item [12] with empty ItemStatusses
- Item [13] with ItemStatusses [13, 21] [13, 21]

For every of these items, you make one new object, with two properties: `Id` and `Statusses`. Id equals the Item.Id.

`Statusses`: from all its ItemStatusses, take only the StatusId, and remove duplicates:

- Item [10]: {[10, 20] [10, 21] [10, 20]} => {20, 21, 20} => {20, 21}
- Item [11]: {[11, 22] [11, 22] [11, 20]} => {22, 22, 20} => {22, 20}
- Item [12]: {} => {} => {}
- Item [13]: {[13, 21] [13, 21]} => {21, 21} => {21}

Now you have unique StatusIds, it is easy to the the descriptions of these statusses:

```
.Select(statusId => dbContext.Statusses.
       .Where(status => status.Id == statusId)
       .Select(status => status.StatusDescription)
       .ToList();
```

Result:

- Item Id 10 with Statusses Ok, NotOk
- Item Id 11 with Statusses Ok, Unknown,
- Item Id 12 without any Statusses
- Item Id 13 with Status NotOk

Answer (score 0):

> (1) I have a mapping table as below: It will have mappings like below with
> duplicated records.
>
> (2) if there is a way to avoid duplicates, that would help

This is an undesirable approach for many-to-many tables. You can try to the instant solution for duplicate rows, but that was not the right solution. First of all, you need to clean the dirty data and then you need to avoid them especially insert them.

```
|--------|----------|
| ItemId | StatusId |
|--------|----------|
|    1   |    1     | OK
|--------|----------|
|    1   |    2     | OK
|--------|----------|
|    1   |    1     | N/A
|--------|----------|
```

You should use the composite key to prevent duplicate rows at the time of insert queries. Thus, throws `'Cannot insert duplicate key'` exception to development environment by db.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ItemStatus> ItemStatuses { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Other relationships
        modelBuilder.Entity<ItemStatus>()
                    .HasKey(x => new { x.ItemId, x.StatusId});
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#alternate-keys

Comment: That's true if ALL the OP has is those two columns. Which is unlikely. Much more likely, is that those are just the significant columns for this question (_"For simplicity, I did not include all the columns"_). In any case, you aren't answering the question that was asked.

Comment: @Auspex Let me try to explain like your way :) So, could you tell me what you understand from this sentence (_It will have mappings like below with duplicated records_) written in the question, especailly what is 'duplicate' for you?

Comment: The fields he _wants_ are duplicated. As he's said, the rows themselves are not all duplicates. OP's question was clearly "I have a table with key columns A, B, and C, and want the _unique_ values of A & B". And still, he didn't ask how to properly index his table, he asked how to get the unique values of those two columns.

Comment: _"For simplicity, I did not include all the columns"_ What could be clearer?

Comment: @Auspex I've already written my opinion and thanked you for writing yours. Nevertheless, I do not understand why you are still asking similar questions, and I thank you for the last time.